# Find and change each 1st char of directory in path string

Tags: bash, lowercase

It's my 1st script in bash and I'm making a script that the bitbucket pipeline will use. I'm trying to change each 1st letter of the directory to lowerCase.
E.g.

`database/Seeders/Entities/Users/Earnings/UserEarningsReportSeeder`

will be changed on

`database/seeders/entities/users/earnings/userEarningsReportSeeder`

Trying with this but not working properly for me :(

`echo "$(echo "$Line" | sed  's/\/[A-Z]/\/L&/g')"`

Comment: pluse-uno for including sample input, required output and ... gasp, some close to working code! Keep posting.

Comment: pluse-uno too for well formated code blocks, good tags. Could be better with a shortest sample input, but kind of nitpicking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this (you was very close):

```
$ sed 's@/[A-Z]@\L&@g' <<< 'Database/Seeders/EarningsFoo'
```

The separator can be any ASCII character, here `@`

##### Output

```
database/seeders/earningsFoo
```

Comment: Thank you! This pattern helped me 's@\/[A-Z]@\L&@g'